# Case_when and or if_else dplyr - when NA use values from another column

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, case-when

I want to use values from a different column to replace NA values. In this example my last four values in my df have NAs in the "count" column - I want the NA's to be replaced with values from the "value" column.

Here is a dummy data set

```
df <- structure(list(First = structure(c(17995, 17997, 17929, 17919, 
17808, 18031, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), Last = 
structure(c(17999, 
17998, 17929, 17919, 17809, 18031, 17965, 17965, 17965, 17965
), class = "Date"), days = c(5, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA
), variable = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("0-12", "0-25", "0-50", "0-100"), class = "factor"), 
value = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), count = c(5, 0, 
1, 1, 2, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

some thoughts of how it might be resolved.... but that are not working due to my poor coding skills:

```
 df <- df %>%
 mutate(a = if_else(count == NA, value, if_else(count >=0, count, a)))
```

or perhaps there is a way with case_when?

Thanks.

Comment: You need `is.na` and not `... == NA` if you want to test if an element is `NA`. Try `df %>% mutate(a = replace(count, is.na(count), value[is.na(count)]))`

Comment: This is what `coalesce` if for. `mutate(a = coalesce(count, value))`.

Answer (score 2):

As has been already said in one of the comments coalesce is the best solution in this case because of NAs:

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(a = coalesce(count, value))
```

but the solution using case_when() in dplyr is useful too:

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(a = case_when(!is.na(count) ~ count,
                              TRUE ~ value))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(a = ifelse(is.na(count), value,
                           ifelse(count >= 0, count, "error")))
```

Answer (score 0):

you are almost there

```
df <- df %>% mutate(a= ifelse(is.na(count), value, count))
```

Comment: This is missing the condition to test if the count is positive value. `count >=0`

Comment: hmm... i think question was to just replace the NA's , in case positive count is needed,                                                                                                     ` mutate( a = ifelse((is.na(count) & count>=0), count, value) `